# Ordering of jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the `btnSubmit` click event callback function fire first, and then the animation 
whereas the `btnSubmit2` event the callback function happens after the animation has finished?

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    $('#testDiv').hide('slow,', onComplete());
});

var onComplete = function () {
    alert('test');
}

$('#btnSubmit2').click(function () {
    $('#testDiv').hide('slow', function () {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="auto" />
        <input type="text" id="auto2" />
    </div> 
    <a id="btnSubmit" href="#">SUBMIT</a>
    <a id="btnSubmit2" href="#">SUBMIT 2</a>

    <div id="testDiv">Here's some test text</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
$('#testDiv').hide('slow,', onComplete());
```

Because you have the parentheses there, you are executing the `onComplete` function immediately.

Try this instead:

```
$('#testDiv').hide('slow,', onComplete);
```

That passes a reference to the function instead of executing it.

Comment: Subtle nuance, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing a function reference

```
$('#testDiv').hide('slow,', onComplete());
```

You're executing the function and passing the return value (`undefined`) to the `hide` method.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the difference between the two piece of code.  In one you are passing an anonymous function with a call to `alert` inside.  The other you are immediately calling your function.

```
$('#testDiv').hide('slow,', onComplete());
```

Should be

```
$('#testDiv').hide('slow,', onComplete);
```

Otherwise you are passing the result of the function as your callback and not the function itself.